# QGIS Technical problem in 'Extract nodes' command

Tags: qgis, geometry-conversion

I am trying to create a layer of nodes from an existing layer of line. For this I am using 
Vector> Geometry Tools > Extract nodes

I, first, select the 'Input polygon vector layer' and then select the output file. After I click on the 'OK' button the process starts and the 'OK' button is grayed out. Even after the process shows 100% completion, the 'OK' button remains grayed out. Hence, I am unable to finish the command and, hence, get the desired output.

Comment: Usually if it is grayed out, it means that it is still processing (you can check the Task Manager to see the CPU performance of QGIS, it will be high if QGIS is performing). How large is your dataset and which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: @Joseph: The Task Manager does not show that QGIS is still processing. The dataset I am using is not large. The shape file is 9 MB. My version of QGIS is 2.4.0

Comment: Do you get the same result if you run **Extract nodes** via the Processing Toolbox?

Comment: @Joseph: When I run Extract nodes via the Processing Toolbox, I get this error message. 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type' See log for more details

Comment: @Joseph please make your comment an answer - it will be voted up.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of things I can think of doing (remember to back up your shapefile!).

- Try *Vector* > *Geometry Tools* > *Check Geometry Validity...* and see if that brings any errors (or alternatively, use **v.clean** from GRASS and select the **snap** tool to snap lines to vertix).
- If you still can't extract nodes, then re-save the shapefile as a new shapefile and try to extract nodes that way.